# segmentation fault when calling c function

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, cygwin

I am new in x86-64 assembly, and I am running a simple x64 assembly code:

```
.global main

.text
main:                                
    mov     $message, %rdi       
    sub     $8, %rsp             
    call    puts                 
    add     $8, %rsp             
    ret                          
message:
    .asciz "Hello, World"
```

After compile the code using gcc under cygwin, it always return me the error:

```
segmentation error
```

but if I remove

```
call puts
```

the program runs without error. So what is the problem with this call out statement?

Comment: You are probably missing part of the function call ABI. This is highly platform dependent. Write an equivalent C programm and compile it with `-S -O3`. The resulting assembler should give you a hint what the platform needs. Generally it is not a good idea to write the function itself in assembler. At least it is much easier to write a wrapper in C and have specific assembler parts inside with `__asm__`.

Answer (score 0):

You must define `message` in the ***read only data*** section...
Like this...

```
.rodata                               # read-only data section
message:
    .string    "Hello, World!"
```

On 32-bit machine,  with AT&T syntax, the code would be as follows...

```
.section .rodata
msg:
    .string    "Hello, World!"        # msg is in the read only data section.

.section .text
    .globl    main
    .type     main, @function
main:
    pushl    %ebp
    movl     %esp, %ebp
    andl     $-16, %esp
    subl     $16,  %esp

    movl     $msg, (%esp)             # We move the argument of puts to (%esp)
    call     puts                     # puts is called

    movl     $0,   (%esp)             # moved the argument of(0) exit to (%esp)
    call     exit                     # exit is called
```